# iOS 8 Jquery Submit Button Focus Bug

Tags: jquery, ipad, ios8

Recently we started to receive some complaints that the button on a page stopped to work under **ipad - ios8**, doing a bit of testing we found that out code when enabling the button and setting the focus() if we had the focus in another place the button would never get the focus and worst it wasn't responding to the click.

Below is a fiddler that simulates this problem, first select the textbox to set the focus on it, then press the button P1 and try to press the Do Something Button.

[Fiddler Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nn7bz19m/)

```js
$("#some_submit_button").prop("disabled",true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="P1" value="P1" onclick="P1Click()" />

<input type="text" id="textP"  />
    
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<input type="submit" id="some_submit_button" value="Do Something" onclick="Submit()" />

<script>
function P1Click() {
    $("#P1").prop("disabled",true);
    $("#some_submit_button").prop("disabled",false);
    $("#some_submit_button").focus();
}
function Submit(){
    alert('Submited the form');
}   
 </script>
```

Did anyone else encountered this bug? Is there an workaround for this?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Same problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/usecode/huggf07j/3/).

Workaround:
Don't set the focus on iPad, iPod, iPhone (mostly people don't use hardware keyboards on these devices to navigate).

```
if((!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) && (!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) && (!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {
    $("#some_submit_button").focus();
} else {
    // hide keyboard on mobile
    $("#textP").blur();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Came across this same issue today. On displaying a dialog box, I give focus to the first focusable element inside the dialog box for keyboard accessibility. In this instance, the first item was a `<input type="submit">` button and Safari on iOS was preventing users from clicking the button.

I have managed to get around it by using `<button type="submit">` instead of `<input type="submit">`.

Personally, I prefer this to browser sniffing. Plus, it retains my keyboard accessibility features.

Issue can be tested here: http://codepen.io/dapenguin/full/rOoaqv